# jQuery ajax call error if only one data param in IE8?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I've got this javascript that works fine in Chrome but in IE the 'data' var passed in the Success function is always an empty string.  What's more my handler is not even hit!

(jQuery 1.6.2)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/rb.ashx",
            type: "GET",
            data: ({ cmd: 'getpmcount' }),
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('unread [' + data + ']'); 
            }
        });
```

if however I add a dummy param to the outgoing data:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/rb.ashx",
            type: "GET",
            data: ({ cmd: 'getpmcount', x:'x' }),
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('unread [' + data + ']'); 
            }
        });
```

it works fine!!

Can anyone explain why this might be the case?  I'd rather have it work properly than have this hack in place.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: are these example 100% accurate? I am asking because most browsers are fault tolerant if you add a trailing comma to a member list of an object literal (eg. { x: 'x', y: 'y', }), but IE will (correctly) give  a syntax error. Maybe that is what's happening?

Comment: I just tested it using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBDXa/) and it works fine for me in IE9 (I have no IE8 installed).

Comment: totally accurate, this was a direct copy/paste from a test page. I've debugged and stack traced in to jQuery and the response code even comes out as 200 even though the server never gets the request.

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle? Have you used the network tab of the developer tools (I assume they are already included in IE8) to see what happens to the request?

Comment: The plot thickens...  I've just pushed my changes to my host and am now seeing in Fiddler 2.3.2.6 that the request is never made in IE where in Chrome it calls to the server as expected (including the dummy param).  Looks like it might be a race condition or something?

I've got another ajax call in another .js file which is working fine (that passes 2 params, hence my initial hunch adding a dummy param).

Looks like the dummy param was a red herring.

Comment: Looks like it was some strange caching issue.  I added 

    cache: false 

to the ajax calls and all is working.

Odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was some strange caching issue. I added cache: false to the ajax calls and all is working. Odd.